# How to implement custom Iterator for multidimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator

I'm currently trying to set up a custom Iterator method for a 2-dimensional array.

E.g. if the array is `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}` the `next()`-method should return successively with every call 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

My idea was something like this:

```
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Type>() {
        private int currentRow = 0;
        private int currentColumn = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentRow < array.length;
        }

        public Type next() {
            if(currentColumn + 1 == array[0].length){
                currentColumn = 0;
                currentRow ++;
            }
            return array[currentRow][currentColumn++];
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't output the items in the right order and sometimes it even returns null.

Comment: Verify that the array contains what you think it contains. Either look at it in a debugger, or write it to stdout using other iteration. Also, have a look at the contract for Iterator. Your next method should throw `NoSuchElementException` if it's called when there is no next element. Also, for robustness and generality, consider checking `array[currentRow].length` rather than `array[0].length`.

Comment: The Arrays class's deepToString method will format 2D array for printing. hasNext should also test the currentColumn value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Type>() {
        private int currentRow = 0;
        private int currentColumn = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (currentRow + 1 == array.length) {
                return currentColumn < array[currentRow].length;
            }
            return currentRow < array.length;
        }

        public Type next() {
            if (currentColumn == array[currentRow].length) {
                currentColumn = 0;
                currentRow++;
            }
            if (currentRow == array.length -1 && currentColumn == array[currentRow].length - 1) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return array[currentRow][currentColumn++];
        }
    };
}
```

Alternatively you can use Java Streams:

```
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .iterator();
}
```

For Integers it would look like this:

```
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(Arrays::stream)
            .flatMap(IntStream::boxed)
            .iterator();
}
```